# Widget menu is not appearing in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am using a customized theme and do not have functions.php. when I use the following link `http://localhost/wanderingthepath/wp-admin/widgets.php`
It displays the following error:

> The theme you are currently using isn’t widget-aware, meaning that it has no sidebars that you are able to change. For information on making your theme widget-aware, ...

Comment: You have cutted away the important part of the error message because it's that part that would have told you so. Additionally support requests about third party software are considered off-topic. Please contact the software vendor for your support options.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request regarding a third party software, here namely Wordpress.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes this is because you not init the widget area, so first make the functions.php file and write the code

```
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
        'id' => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

By this code your widget area is activated.

Comment: Hi. Adi, its works in latest wordpress, thanks it quick resolve it, please keep sharing